# Nohup for Python script not working when running in the background with &

Tags: python, linux, nohup

Boiling down to the smallest problem here is a simple python script that I want to run using nohup on linux. I run it using the following (on linux):

```
nohup python test.py &
```

The command seems to just not do anything, nothing is appended to nohup.out. If I run it without the & the output shows correctly on the terminal window. What am I missing?

```
import time

def test():
    while(True):
      print "Woke up!"
      time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pass python the -u flag for unbuffering stdout

```
nohup python -u test.py &
```

Python will buffer stdout otherwise. This doesn't require a code change.

From the man page:

```
       -u     Force  stdin,  stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout
          and stderr in binary mode.  Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and  file-object
          iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by this option.  To work around this, you will want
          to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
```

Comment: I was having problems with a python script not running with nohup and this fixed it. Much gracias.

Answer (score 4):

You need to flush `stdout` after printing: `sys.stdout.flush()`; otherwise it'll take awhile to fill the stdout buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Just had a similar issue. My script worked well without nohup. With nohup, the script would crash with a SyntaxError.

The problem was the execution context of nohup which would use an alias of `python` mapped to `python2` instead of `python3`.

Fixed it by specifying `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: You're a life savior !!! Thanks a lot man : )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however, my algorithm was a little more complex than yours demonstrated. As I had created a python virtual environment by installing all the necessary packages for its execution, it only runs if the virtual environment is activated `source env/bin/activate`. After activating the environment, I was able to run normally, not resulting in any errors: `nohup python3 -u scriptShow.py > logScriptNohup.log &`.

If you want to make sure it's running, do in the terminal: `ps aux | grep scriptShow`. If the running process appears, congratulations, you did it